# Getting redirected after login but I am not actually logged in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Update: I tried implemting a CSRF token, and now when I try to log in, I always get redirected to the default Spring login page localhost:8080/login, and when I log in there again, it again redirects me to the login successful url....

This is my WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    AccountDetailsService accountDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(accountDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/me").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(   HttpMethod.POST,"/api/addthing", "/api/addotherthing").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("http://192.168.1.105:3000/api/adminpage", true)
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("http://192.168.1.105:3000/")
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Here's my AccountDetailsService

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class AccountDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account account = accountService.findAccountByUsername(username);

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                account.getUsername(), account.getPassword(),
                true, true, true, true,
                accountService.getAuthorities(account)
        );
    }
}
```

Also the AccountSrvice:

```
@Service
public class AccountService {
    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public Account findAccountByUsername(String username){
        return accountRepository.findFirstByUsername(username);
    }

    public List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Account account){
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        String role = account.getRole();
        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        return roles;
    }

    public void createNewAccount(String username, String password, String role) {
        Account account = new Account(username, passwordEncoder.encode(password), role);
        accountRepository.save(account);
    }
}
```

The problem that I am having is, after logging in, I get redirected to the `/api/adminpage/` site, which means that the login is successful, right? But when I try getting my Principal with this method:

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/api/me")
    public Principal getMe(Principal principal){
        return principal;
    }
```

It just gives me an empty response, which means that I am not logged in.. Also when I try making a POST request to some of the urls in antMatches I can't... Can someone explain what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my whole day is now gone on this stupid little thing, but I got it working, and I'm not even happy about it anymore

The fix was to add `"proxy": "http://192.168.1.105:8080"` in my `package.json` in the React app.